# How to save input default value in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on my first project and I found another problem. My professor told me, my edit form can't be empty at start and it has to store default values. And that's what I've made. Sadly I found it problematic. What's wrong? 
First thing:
*My default input can't be changed. 
Second:
*Even when my default value is visible for me, after POST it sends "" as value.

I've tried a lot of things, like setting value from this.state.userResponse.map, but ofcourse it fails. Even tried to escape React and save default values into LocalStorage only to make it work.

```
class EditProtege extends Component {
  state = {
    firstname: "",
    userResponse: []
  };

  getUserByID() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:9000/proteges/${utils.i}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ userResponse: res }))
      .catch(err => err);
  }

  handleNameChange = event => {
    this.setState({ firstname: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .put(`http://localhost:9000/proteges/${utils.i}`, {
        firstname: this.state.firstname,
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      });

    window.location.reload();
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserByID();
    //this.setDefaultValues();
  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <div className="creation-form">
        {this.state.userResponse.map(resp => (
        <div>
          <br />
          <rb.Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <rb.FormGroup>
              <rb.Row>
                <rb.Col md={12}>
                  <rb.FormControl
                    type="text"
                    name="firstname"
                    size="md"
                    onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                    placeholder="Name"
                    default={this.userResponse.proteges}
                    required
                  />
                </rb.Col>
            </rb.FormGroup>
            <rb.Button type="submit" variant="dark" size="lg" block>
               Zatwierdź edycję
            </rb.Button>
          </rb.FormGroup>
        </rb.Form>
      </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditProtege;
```

Like I've said before, I want to POST default value and to be able to change it if I want to. Now its untouchable and sends empty string.

UPDATE: changed default into defaultValue and it seems like I can edit it again, still, problem with saving this data still occurs.

Comment: If `handleNameChange` is never called, `state.firstName` remains its default value `""`. Where could you set a default value for the state such that if `handleNameChange` were never called prior to submit, `state.firstName` would contain the default value you desire?

Comment: What does the `default` prop on the `FormControl` component actually do? Why can't you simply use the `value` attribute of the `input` element to control your component properly?

Comment: Now I'm a little bit confused, but if I'm not wrong, using value made my input constant, can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting your state's firstName to a default value, then use the value attribute on your rb input component and set it to this.state.firstName while still keeping the onChange in place and get rid of the default attribute.

This way, each time you change the input value of your field, the state will be reset effectively, and it will also update the input field value. When you send your post request with the current state data, it should be accurate as well.

Comment: It's not so easy to set it as default value, because I have multiple "proteges" and based on ID default changes.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether your getUserById returns the kind of data that you'd use to populate the fields that you need to set default values for?